iOS SwiftUI Image copy after applying effects
I have an iOS image to which I have applied scale, offset and rotation to, and then clipped. How can I get a copy of the image (or save a copy) with these effects applied?
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("minions")
            .resizable()
            .scaleEffect(1.5)
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(20.0))
            .offset(CGSize(width: -75.0, height: -50.0))
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(width: 160, height: 160, alignment: .center)
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .clipped()
            .border(Color.black)
    }
}

I have tried ImageRenderer to export bitmap image data from the view, however I only get a copy of the original image without the effects:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var image1 = Image("minions")
    var image2 = Image("empty")

    var body: some View {
        image1
            .resizable()
            .scaleEffect(1.5)
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(20.0))
            .offset(CGSize(width: -75.0, height: -50.0))
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(width: 160, height: 160, alignment: .center)
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .clipped()
            .border(Color.black)

        Button(action: {
            let imageRenderer = ImageRenderer(content: image1)
            image2 = Image(uiImage: imageRenderer.uiImage!)
        }, label: {
            Text("Copy Image")
        })
    
        image2
    }
}


Please show a [mre] of how you used ImageRenderer. Also show what the original image is, and what ImageRenderer produced.

The modifiers you added to image1 doesn't change what "image1" means. image1 still refers to the original image.
You should pass the whole image1.resizable().scaleEffect(1.5)... expression, with all those modifiers, into ImageRenderer. Of course, you'd get a lot of code duplication this way, so to avoid that, assign the image1 expression with all those modifiers to a local variable first.
struct ContentView: View {
    var image1 = Image("1")
    @State var image2: Image?

    var body: some View {
        // assign this to a local variable first
        let image = image1
            .resizable()
            .scaleEffect(1.5)
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(20.0))
            .offset(CGSize(width: -75.0, height: -50.0))
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(width: 160, height: 160, alignment: .center)
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .clipped()
            .border(Color.black)

        // this shows it on the view
        image

        Button(action: {
            // pass the image to the ImageRenderer
            let imageRenderer = ImageRenderer(content: image)
            image2 = Image(uiImage: imageRenderer.uiImage!)
        }, label: {
            Text("Copy Image")
        })
    
        image2
    }
}

